# Gentoo kvm guest integrations (vmchannel)

Tags: kernel, kvm, gentoo, virtio

I'm trying to get a working [VMchannel](https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/VMchannel_Requirements) to my gentoo kvm guest.

I enabled the [recommended kernel options for gentoo guests](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/QEMU/Linux_guest).
As the channel appears to be a character device, I also enabled `Virtio console` under `Character devices`.

Despite that, it seems that the guest doesn't have any device like `/dev/vport0p1`.
My fedora guest, for example, the devices show up without a problem (and the guest integrations work too). Unfortunately, I couldn't find much of a difference in `dmesg` or `lspci` compared to the working guest so far.

This is what a `vport` looks like on fedora:

```
# udevadm info /dev/vport2p1
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/0000:02:00.0/virtio2/virtio-ports/vport2p1
N: vport2p1
L: 0
S: virtio-ports/com.redhat.spice.0
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/0000:02:00.0/virtio2/virtio-ports/vport2p1
E: DEVNAME=/dev/vport2p1
E: MAJOR=242
E: MINOR=1
E: SUBSYSTEM=virtio-ports
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=4427561
E: SYSTEMD_WANTS=spice-vdagentd.socket
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/virtio-ports/com.redhat.spice.0
E: TAGS=:systemd:
```

Am I just missing a kernel option, a udev rule or something like that? And: what are the basic requirements (for the guest/kernel) to establish a channel to a guest?

---

```
Kernel version: 5.4.80-gentoo #3
```

Enabled options:

```
BLK_MQ_VIRTIO
VIRTIO_BLK
VIRTIO_BLK_SCSI
SCSI_VIRTIO
VIRTIO_NET
VIRTIO_CONSOLE
HW_RANDOM_VIRTIO
DRM_VIRTIO_GPU
VIRTIO
VIRTIO_MENU
VIRTIO_PCI
VIRTIO_BALLOON
VIRTIO_INPUT
VIRTIO_MMIO
VIRTIO_MMIO_CMDLINE_DEVICES
VIRTIO_FS
DRM_QXL (but I'm using virgl/virtio_gpu right now)
```

Disabled oprtions:

```
VIRTIO_PCI_LEGACY
```

Channels in my vm config:

```
<channel type="unix">
  <target type="virtio" name="org.qemu.guest_agent.0"/>
  <address type="virtio-serial" controller="0" bus="0" port="1"/>
</channel>
<channel type="spicevmc">
  <target type="virtio" name="com.redhat.spice.0"/>
  <address type="virtio-serial" controller="0" bus="0" port="2"/>
</channel>
```

Answer (score 1):

I realize it's been over 2 months; but try this:

If you boot the VM from the Gentoo install cd, you *should* see `vport*` character devices listed in `/dev`, along with a `virtio-ports` directory.  Give that a try, and confirm them.

From the CD *and* booted from an install I did yesterday, I see this:

```
# ls -l /dev/vport*
crw------- 1 root root 250, 1 Feb 11 04:53 /dev/vport1p1
crw------- 1 root root 250, 2 Feb 11 04:53 /dev/vport1p2
# ls -l /dev/virtio-ports
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 11 Feb 11 04:53 com.redhat.spice.0 -> ../vport1p2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 11 Feb 11 04:53 org.qemu.guest_agent.0 -> ../vport1p1
```

If all is well, continue, as if performing a fresh install.

Make a backup of your current `/usr/src/linux` directory, and your current `/boot` files.

Then `chroot` just like in the installation instructions. Compile using GENKERNEL, as such:

```
(chroot) livecd / # cd /usr/src/linux
(chroot) livecd / # make mrproper
(chroot) livecd / # make defconfig
# ~~~
### 5.4 kernel version, prior to kernel v.5.10 -- the kvmconfig target is available:
(chroot) livecd / # make kvmconfig
# ~~~
### 
(chroot) livecd / # genkernel --virtio --menuconfig all
```

Then, following the tips from that [Gentoo wiki page](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/QEMU/Linux_guest) like you did before, also see [this page](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/User:Flow/Gentoo_as_KVM_guest), and set those recommended kernel options. Boot with that new kernel, see what you get in /dev.

Comment: The actual problem was that my boot partition wasn't mounted. I installed the kernel into a 'boot' folder on another partition. Oops! After fixing that, `/dev/vport1p1`, etc showed up correctly. But I didn't check all the guest funtionality yet.